# Convert a Base64 string into a map in Elixir

Tags: json, elixir

I am using Elixir to decode a Base64 string which contains a JSON.
I use the following function:

> Base.url_decode64(string)

However, this function returns a string. In particular:

> "{\"algorithm\":\"HMAC-SHA256\",\"app_data\":\"1\",\"issued_at\":1452249105,\"page\":{\"id\":\"1051194981579510\",\"admin\":true},\"user\":{\"country\":\"se\",\"locale\":\"en_GB\",\"age\":{\"min\":21}}}"

The problem is that this structure should be a map instead of a string because otherwise I can't access the JSON fields.

The question is: how can I convert this string into a map?
Or: how can I treat this string as a map and access anyway the single fields?

Comment: If @Gazler's answer is the right solution for you, you should accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a JSON library. There are several, one commonly used one is [Poison](https://hex.pm/packages/poison) (there are others on [hex](https://hex.pm/packages?search=json&sort=downloads)):

```
string |> Base.url_decode64 |> Poison.decode!
```

This uses the [Poison.decode!/2](http://hexdocs.pm/poison/Poison.html#decode!/2) function.

Whenever I use I like to alias it as JSON so that I don't have references to `Poison` throughout my code:

```
alias Poison, as: JSON
string |> Base.url_decode64 |> JSON.decode!
```

Comment: Are you using alias so that you could later swap JSON libraries?

Comment: @ChrisMeyer Yeah, that is the main reason. The other is that I don't have to remember that Poison is a json library.