# Convert string representation of an array of json objects to map Elixir

Tags: json, elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-poison

Here I have a payload coming to my controller action endpoint:

```
%{      
  "mandrill_events" => "[{\"event\":\"send\",\"msg\":{\"ts\":1365109999,\"subject\":\"This an example webhook message\",\"email\":\"example.webhook@mandrillapp.com\",\"sender\":\"example.sender@mandrillapp.com\",\"tags\":[\"webhook-example\"],\"opens\":[],\"clicks\":[],\"state\":\"sent\",\"metadata\":{\"user_id\":111},\"_id\":\"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\",\"_version\":\"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\"},\"_id\":\"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\",\"ts\":1518203456},{\"event\":\"send\",\"msg\":{\"ts\":1365109999,\"subject\":\"This an example webhook message\",\"email\":\"example.webhook@mandrillapp.com\",\"sender\":\"example.sender@mandrillapp.com\",\"tags\":[\"webhook-example\"],\"opens\":[],\"clicks\":[],\"state\":\"sent\",\"metadata\":{\"user_id\":111},\"_id\":\"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1\",\"_version\":\"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\"},\"_id\":\"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1\",\"ts\":1518203456}]"
}
```

I am trying to decode the content of `mandrill_events`, so that I can then access some values, but I think the bracket is throwing it off.

```
get_in(payload, ["mandrill_events"]) |> Base.url_decode64 |> Poison.decode!
```

But that didn't work either.

```
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.iolist_to_binary(:error)
    (poison) lib/poison/parser.ex:35: Poison.Parser.parse/2
    (poison) lib/poison/parser.ex:51: Poison.Parser.parse!/2
    (poison) lib/poison.ex:83: Poison.decode!/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:250: IEx.Evaluator.handle_eval/5
    (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:230: IEx.Evaluator.do_eval/3
    (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:208: IEx.Evaluator.eval/3
    (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:94: IEx.Evaluator.loop/1
    (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:24: IEx.Evaluator.init/4
```

Comment: Why do you need to do: `Base.url_decode64` ? `get_in(a, ["mandrill_events"]) |> Poison.decode!` should be sufficient. When you do `|> Base.url_decode64` it throws an error

Comment: found about it on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34675180/3307520

Comment: In your case, you already have your JSON string. Look at this: `get_in(a, ["mandrill_events"]) |> Base.url_encode64` That will generate a base64 encoded version of the json payload so it can be transmitted safely, without it getting altered. In such a case, it needs to be decoded first so you have your JSON string, then you can `|> Poison.decode!` to convert to elixir term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: `get_in(a, ["mandrill_events"]) |> Poison.decode!` should give you what you want.

The reason as to why the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34675044/convert-a-base64-string-into-a-map-in-elixir/34675180#34675180) includes the operation `|> Base.url_decode64` is because that question was dealing with base64 encoded payloads. [Base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is simply a way of mapping a payload to a subset of the ASCII characters that are guaranteed to be recognized by every router, so that the payload value does not get corrupted when in transit.

For example, you could do:

`get_in(a, ["mandrill_events"]) |> Base.url_encode64`

which will render something like this:

```
"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"
```

When you are dealing with `base64` encoded payload, you will need to first decode it so you get a JSON string which in turn you can deserialize using Poison.

As a full sanity test, the following would work as well:

`get_in(a, ["mandrill_events"]) |> Base.url_encode64 |> Base.url_decode64 |> Poison.decode!`

Of course, if the string is not base64 encoded, and you try to base64 decode it accordingly as you currently are doing, then it will throw an `:error` which Poison does not know how to convert to an elixir term as its input is to be a JSON string, not an `atom`